# emacs text mode UTF-8 characters

Tags: emacs, locale, xterm, unicode

I can't get emacs (version 24.4.1) in text mode (`-nw` launch option) to display Unicode characters directly. It outputs them in escaped form, e.g. `ä` becomes `\344`. When I save the file, it is encoded as `ISO-8859`, even though my system locale is `en_US.UTF-8`.

The terminal itself can display Unicode characters *outside* of emacs; e.g., in bash, `ä` becomes `ä`. It also works in the emacs X application (without `-nw`).

I'm running `xterm -u8` (same result using `uxterm`) on Arch Linux 3.19.3-3 with gnome-shell 3.16.0-2.

**`localectl` output:**

```
   System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
       VC Keymap: sv-latin1
      X11 Layout: se
       X11 Model: pc104
```

**`locale` output:**

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Since the only problem area is emacs in terminal mode, I'm guessing that's where the problem is. Any ideas?

**Update:**

**`~/.emacs`:**

```
(prefer-coding-system       'utf-8)
(set-default-coding-systems 'utf-8)
(set-terminal-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-keyboard-coding-system 'utf-8)

(setq x-select-request-type '(UTF8_STRING COMPOUND_TEXT TEXT STRING))
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(ansi-color-names-vector
   ["#2d3743" "#ff4242" "#74af68" "#dbdb95" "#34cae2" "#008b8b" "#00ede1" "#e1e1e0"])
 '(current-language-environment "UTF-8")
 '(custom-enabled-themes (quote (manoj-dark)))
 '(font-use-system-font t)
 '(inhibit-startup-screen t)
 '(tool-bar-mode nil))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
```

I tried commenting out every line in the file, but the result was the same afterwards.

Comment: Just fyi, there is now a emacs.stackexchange.com. Your question might be on topic there.

Comment: @Faheem This kind of system-specific problem is usually best handled on an OS-specific site. In any case, svenper, don't b repost.

Comment: Do you have a `.emacs` file? What version of Emacs are you running?

Comment: Emacs version 24.4.1. I'll update the OP with the .emacs file.

Comment: @Gilles Ok, noted. It was just for the poster's reference. A surprising number of people do not know the Emacs SE site exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some fiddling, I found it was system-related rather than emacs-related. Apparently my locale settings were messed up somehow, as we saw in the OP:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
```

What I did to resolve it:

In `/etc/locale.gen`, uncomment/add the line that says `en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8`. Make sure it’s the only uncommented line. It should work with any other `UTF-8` setting if you’d rather use one of those. A brute force method would be:

```
$ sudo bash -c 'echo en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8 > /etc/locale.gen'
```

After this we generate the locale settings and store them in the system configuration:

```
$ sudo locale-gen
$ sudo bash -c 'locale > /etc/locale.conf'
```

You may be able to update the settings without rebooting, but I didn’t find a way.